# Too many inode usage

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, inode

I'm using Ubuntu 14.x, and recently attempting to create files failed with some kind of disk is full message.

I had more than 2gb spaces and that's not possible, but I heard that it can causes if inode is full.

I'm not skilled linux user, so I don't get it how to remove them. First what I do was typing this above command as root to see how many inodes were used:

```
$ df -i -h
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             248K   414  248K    1% /dev
tmpfs            250K   467  250K    1% /run
/dev/xvda1       512K  512K     0  100% /
```

Yeah, it's 100%. Then I found the command that shows how much inodes were used in current system:

```
#  for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

It prints this:

```
/bin
172
/boot
353
/dev
416
/etc
1971
/home
21808
/lib
17720
/proc
43272
/sys
36453
/tmp
5134
/usr
423458
/var
10117
...
```

So I deleted some files in /home/dev, and I got some free inodes back, but not much:

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       512K  464K   49K   91% /
```

Besides, when I re-install the files that I needed, it takes inodes again, so this actually not solved.

I saw that /usr directory takes almost of inodes: 423458, but I don't know which files can I remove that doesn't affect other system or programs.

How do I find "unnessecary" inodes to delete? Any advice will very appreciate it.

Comment: Show output of command:  find /usr/ -xdev -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n | tail

Comment: You have too many files.

Comment: When this sort of problem, the file system is normally populated with a large number of tiny files. If this a recent issue, then you can find files in the file system based on date and size.

Comment: "unnecessary" is hard to answer, but see the linked question for ways to find where those files are

Comment: This can be because of linux kernel image and headers taking up a lot of the inodes.Check this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/remove-old-kernels-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to my system you have a lot of files in `/usr`, so I would suggest continuing the search there, if you just change `/*` to `*` in the command it will work in any directory. If you don't have anything to compare the numbers with it might become difficult though. Here's the count of files I have in the subdirectories of `/usr`:

```
bin 2397
games 32
include 4607
lib 27379
local 34
sbin 271
share 1
src 22971
```

(made with `for i in *; do echo -n "$i "; find $i |wc -l; done`)